# Склоняется ли женская фамилия Пристая?

Tags: грамматика, склонение-фамилий

Скажите, пожалуйста, склоняется ли женская фамилия Пристая?

Answer (score 1):

Из [пособия](https://online-edu.ranepa.ru/pluginfile.php/30832/mod_page/content/9/2020-09_BCM_02-lit_2.pdf) для государственных гражданских и муниципальных служащих "Русский язык и культура деловой переписки" (О. В. Котлярова, М. А. Черных, стр. 42):

> Если **фамилия оканчивается на гласный *-я*, которому предшествует другой гласный** (*Шенгелая, Ломая, Рея, Берия, Данелия*), она **склоняется**. Примеры: *тетрадь Инны Шенгелаи, диплом выдан Николаю Ломае, встреча с Анной Реей; преступления Лаврентия Берии, встреча с Георгием Данелией.*

Точно такое же [правило](https://gramota.ru/biblioteka/spravochniki/azbuchnye-istiny/istiny-8-familii) имеется  в «Справочном бюро» «Грамоты.ру».

Итак, фамилия Пристая (оканчивается на ***-ая***) склоняется: *Пристой, Пристой, Пристую, Пристой, Пристой.*

P. S. В предыдущем ответе на сайте *analizfamilii.ru* имеется ошибка в склонении (в родительном падеже).

Answer (score 0):

1. Фамилия ***Пристая***  склоняется.
2. **У [Грамоты](https://gramota.ru/poisk?query=surnames&mode=spravka)** есть объяснение для похожей фамилии ***Патарая***, которая тоже склоняется.

   ```
   Склоняемость-несклоняемость фамилий, пишущихся с буквой я 
   на конце, зависит только от места ударения и 
   происхождения фамилии.
   Несклоняемы фамилии французского происхождения с 
   ударением на конце: Золя, Труайя.
   Все прочие фамилии на я склоняемы; таковы Головня, 
   Зозуля, Сырокомля, Гамалея, Гойя, Шенгелая, Данелия, 
   Берия.
   Таким образом, согласно правилам, фамилия Патарая 
   склоняется и в женском, и в мужском вариантах.
   ```
3. Другое дело, как склоняется: **по образцу прилагательных или существительных?**  Скорее всего, как существительное (можно проверить именем ***Тая***).

**[Склонение и ударение в слове «Шенгелая»](https://udarenieru.ru/index.php?doc=%D0%A8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%8F)**

```
    ед.ч.       мн.ч.
И.  Шенгелая    Шенгелаи
Р.  Шенгелаи    Шенгелай
Д.  Шенгелае    Шенгелаям
В.  Шенгелаю    Шенгелай
Т.  Шенгелаей   Шенгелаями
П.  Шенгелае    Шенгелаях
```

**[История фамилии Пристая.](https://namesdb.ru/pristaya/)**

Answer (score 0):

Дополнительные **размышления** (без правил)

Автор вопроса не указал, на какой слог падает ударение в фамилии.
Предположим — ***При́стая***.
Вот подходящие прилагательные с таким ударением (трехсложные) и соответствующим склонением:
*бри́тая, чи́стая, би́тая, кры́тая* (чи́стой, чи́стую).

Предположим — ***Приста́я***.
Тогда подходят для сравнения такие слова: *проста́я, пуста́я, свята́я*, у которых такое же склонение (просто́й, просту́ю).

Попробуем просклонять как существительное (кроме слова *стая*, ничего не вспомнилось):
стаи (Приста́и), стае (Приста́е), стаю (Приста́ю), стаей (Приста́ей), о стае (о Приста́е).

Мне видится, что склонение по типу прилагательных лучше, "комфортнее" для восприятия.

Answer (score 0):

Добавлю еще один ответ (с размышлением).

**ГЛАВНОЕ.**  Фамилия склоняется. Это все, что можно однозначно утверждать. **Вариант склонения** уточняйте на **сайте Грамота.ру**. У них больше возможностей для **обоснованного** ответа. А здесь только **размышления**))

1. **ПРИМЕР**

Грамота ясно говорит про фамилии на -***ЦКАЯ***.Там два варианта (как **существительные** и как **прилагательные**). Форма у них такая **двойственная.**

```
 № 249526
 Скажите, пожалуйста, склоняются ли женские фамилии на "- 
 цкая"? (Например, Гурцкая, Трубецкая) — меня интересует 
 форма творительного падежа.

 ОТВЕТ
 Женские личные имена и мужские и женские фамилии, 
 оканчивающиеся на -ая, склоняются. Фамилия Гурцкая 
 склоняется следующим образом (на примере мужской фамилии): 
 Александр Гурцкая, Александра Гурцкаи, Александру Гурцкае, 
 Александра Гурцкаю, Александром Гурцкаей, об Александре 
 Гурцкае. Женская фамилия Гурцкая склоняется аналогично.

Фамилия Трубецкая (Трубецкой) склоняется как прилагательное: 
Трубецкой, Трубецкую.
```

2. А почему **Трубецкая, [Осадчая,](https://sklonenie-slova.ru/familiya/osadchiy) Плисецкая** склоняются как **прилагательное**? И ударение вот разное.

Задумались...  Структура слов разная. Вот напишем ***Гурецкая*** и точно будем склонять как прилагательное.  Тогда оно будет **похоже** на прилагательное.

3. А у нас как? **[Происхождение фамилии](https://famiry.ru/database/surnames/pristai)**

   ```
   Фамилия Пристай является относительно редкой в русском и 
   украинском языках, и хотя ее точное происхождение 
   остается  загадкой, существует несколько версий о том, 
   как она могла возникнуть и каким образом можно 
   интерпретировать ее значение.
   Слово «пристай» в старинных текстах и документах 
   использовалось для обозначения прихода или пребывания 
   кого-либо в определенном месте. Некоторые исследователи 
   считают, что фамилия могла возникнуть от слова «пристой» 
   или «пристойный», которые означали «честный» или 
   «порядочный»
   ```

Склонение по образцу прилагательных ***простой, пристайный, пристойный***?

Нет, не похоже слово "пристая"  на **русское прилагательное** при любом ударении. Поэтому скорее здесь склонение по образцу **существительного**.  Для образца возьмем имя ***Тая***:

***Тая — Таи — Тае — Таю — Таей — о Тае.***

***Пристая — Пристаи — Пристае — Пристаю — Пристаей — о Пристае.***

Только вот **утверждать** ничего не будем. **По документам** образец склонения определяется **ОДНОЗНАЧНО.**

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

1. А **мужская** фамилия по образцу прилагательного ***Пристой***? Пара получается странная: он Пристой, а она Пристая.

А это склонение **мужской** фамилии по образцу существительного и прилагательного:

*Николай Пристая, тетрадь Николая Пристаи, диплом выдан Николаю Пристае.*

*Николай Пристой, тетрадь Николая Пристого, диплом выдан Николаю Пристому.*

2. **И еще любопытно:** а бывает ли **смешанное** склонение?  Вот в такое верится с трудом)  Это чтобы часть падежей была как у прилагательных, а часть как у существительных. Или еще странный вариант: **повтор одной** формы в разных падежах? Это было бы очень **неудобно** для обладателя фамилии. Но можем же мы представить это хотя бы **в размышлениях)**
3. И мой заключительный **ВЫВОД** по данной **лингвистической ситуации.** Чем **необычнее** фамилия, тем больше вероятность, что слово склоняется по образцу **существительных,** а не прилагательных (что характерно для большинства **русских** фамилий).

Это на тему **комфортности** восприятия грамматической формы **носителями** языка.